Subgroup structure of $Out(F_n)$
The Section 9.5 of Topological Methods in Group Theory of R. Geoghegan aims to prove the following result:

Theorem 9.5.5 The group $Out(F_n)$ is of type $F_{\infty}$. Every torsion-free subgroup has geometric dimension $\leq 2n-3$. If $H$ is a finite-index torsion-free subgroup, then there is a $K(H,1)$-complex $(2n-3)$-dimensional and the geometric dimension of $H$ is precisely $(2n-3)$.

PS: A group $G$ has type $F_n$ if there is a $K(G,1)$-complex having finite $n$-skeleton. A group $G$ has type $F_{\infty}$ iff $G$ has type $F_n$ for all $n$.

First we construct a simplical complex $K_n$ on which $Out(F_n)$ acts with finite stabilizers and $K_n$ is finite modulo $Out(F_n)$. Also, $K_n$ has dimension $2n-3$. This is an exercise which I solved.
He "proves" the following results:
Theorem 9.5.2 The space $|K_n|$ is contactible.
Proposition 9.5.3 The group $Out(F_n)$ has a torsion-free subgroup of finite index.
Proposition 9.5.4 The group $Out(F_n)$ contains a free abelian subgroup of rank $2n-3$.
The proof of Theorem 9.5.2 is hard. I take a look in the paper of Culler and Vogtmann, but I'm not able to understand well all the steps.
He writes a sketch of the proof of Proposition 9.5.3 but I can complete the details.
I can complete the proof of Proposition 9.5.4 with a help of Lee Mosher in a previous question on this forum.
The authors says that this facts proves Theorem 9.5.5.

Now,
let $H$ be any torsion-free subgroup of $Out(F_n)$. Note that $H$ acts on the $CW$-complex $K_n$ with action induced by the action of $Out(F_n)$. We have that $K_n$ is contractible and $(2n-3)$-dimensional. Also, since the action of $Out(F_n)$ have finite stabilizers and $H$ is torsion-free, then $H$ acts freely on $K_n$. It follows that $K_n$ is a free $CW$ complex. So the quotient will be a $(2n-3)$-dimensional $K(H,1)$-complex, hence, the geometric dimension of $H$ is $\leq 2n-3$.
I think this idea proves the middle claim of Theorem 9.5.5.
by Proposition 9.5.3 $Out(F_n)$ has a torsion-free subgroup $G$ of finite index so that the action of $G$ on $K_n$ is free. Using the same idea to prove the middle claim, since $G$ has finite index and $K_n$ is finite modulo $Out(F_n)$, then $K_n$ is finite modulo $G$. Since we take the quotient, then the $K(G,1)$-complex is finite. This is the definition of "$G$ has type $F$" and if $G$ has type $F$, then $G$ has type $F_{\infty}$. By Corollary 7.2.4 of the book, $Out(F_n)$ has type $F_{\infty}$.
I think this idea proves the first claim.
In order to prove the last claim: if $H$ has a free abelian subgroup of rank $2n-3$, then $H$ has geometric dimension $2n-3$. So I suppose that we should use Proposition 9.5.4, but how? If we set $A$ the be the free abelian subgroup of rank $2n-3$ of $Out(F_n)$, is $H \cap A$ a free abelian subgroup of rank $2n-3$ of $H$?

The last claim of the theorem is concerned with the case that $H$ is a torsion free finite index subgroup. The intersection $A \cap H$ is therefore a finite index subgroup of $A$. Since $A$ is free abelian of rank $2n-3$, it follows that $A \cap H$ is also free abelian of rank $2n-3$.

Oh, right! I was looking to $A \cap H$ only as a subgroup of $H$!
